# NoMethodError during Lynda Rails 3 tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**What is wrong and how can I fix it?**

I get the following error when I run `me = AdminUser.find(1)` then run `me.section.edits`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `section' for #<AdminUser:0x007fa539ee0558>
   from ...gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
   from ...gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
```

My code

**create_section_edits.rb**

```
class SectionEdit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :name, :position
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => "AdminUser", :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'
  belongs_to :section
end
```

**admin_user.rb**

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :username, :first_name, :last_name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  has_many :section_edits
  scope :named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name => first, :last_name => last)}
end
```

**section.rb**

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :name, :position
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :section_edits
end
```

**section_edit.rb**

```
class SectionEdit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :name, :position
  belongs_to :editor, :class_name => "AdminUser", :foreign_key => 'admin_user_id'
  belongs_to :section
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdminUser has no relationship with `sections`, but with `section_edits` only.

So, instead of

```
me.section.edits
```

You need to use

```
me.section_edits
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is the fact that Admins can have multiple sections through section_edits.

Your association needs to look like this

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :username, :first_name, :last_name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
  has_many :section_edits
  has_many :sections, through: :section_edits
  scope :named, lambda {|first,last| where(:first_name => first, :last_name => last)}
end
```

Note the has_many through allows you to call `me.sections`